# How do I send someone else TF2 replay files?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What files do I need to include when sending someone else a replay?  Just the numbered ones from the same group in `\steamapps\[username]\team fortress 2\tf\replay\client\blocks` or does that need to be paired with all the other meta-ones in `\sessions` and `\replays`?

Answer (score 2):

That is the only folder you need, however the person receiving the files should take a backup of their folder before using yours as they may have some of the same file names which will get overwritten. I can only vouch for it if you're sending it to someone who also recorded something on the same map however.